# ng repeat order by over php json_encode data

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

i am creating an array of my database in php and sending it using json_encode

this the the var_dump of array

```
array (size=2)
'latestDate' => string '2015-08-27 07:30:34'
 'rcList' => 
   array (size=3)
   '0' => 
      array (size=4)
      'name' => string 'somesite' 
       'url' => string 'http://www.somesite/rss' 
       'overrideurl' => string 'http://www.somesite/latest' 
       'site' => string 'http://somesite/' 
   '1' => 
     array 
       'name' => string 'somesite1' 
       'url' => string 'http://somesite1/rss' 
       'overrideurl' => null
       'site' => string 'http://somesite1.in/' 
    '2' => 
     array (size=4)
       'name' => string 'somesite3' 
       'url' => string 'http://somesite3/rss'
       'overrideurl' => null
       'site' => string 'http://somesite3/'
```

I am getting the data ok and i am able to display it using ng-repeat.

However i am unable to sort it

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in List | orderBy:item.name"                                            ui-sref="tabs.feed({ rcData:rc})">  
            <b>{{item.name|uppercase}}</b><br>
  </div>
```

I know that ng-repeat only works with arrays but what i get from php is json so how do i convert it to array so i can sort it?

The JSON data is like so:

```
{
"latestDate": "2015-08-27 07:30:34",
"rcList": [
 {
  "name": "somesite",
  "url": "http://www.somesite/rss",
  "overrideurl": "http://www.somesite/latest",
  "site": "http://somesite/"
},
{
  "name": "somesite1",
  "url": "http://somesite1/rss",
  "overrideurl": "",
  "site": "http://somesite1.in/"
},
{
  "name": "somesite3",
  "url": "http://somesite3/rss",
  "overrideurl": null,
  "site": "http://somesite3/"
 }
 ]
 }
```

Is this a good data structure..if not what kind or structure should i use

Answer (score 0):

When using the `orderBy` filter you do not need to include the object name, only the property name:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in List | orderBy:name" ui-sref="tabs.feed({ rcData: rc })">  
    <b>{{item.name|uppercase}}</b><br>
</div>
```

Comment: i did that but it still does not work..the problem is that i am getting nested  json..i cannot seem to get to traverse through it

Comment: Can you post the JSON?